# Combo list focus on Click event- SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

I have a drop down control with first item as blank. But usually when the user will land on the page, there will be a value selected. User can click on the arrow in combobox to open the list and then choose the first option which is blank to clear the value. Issue is the list of options is too long and as the control always focusses/takes user to the option that was selected key, the user has to do some scrolling to reach the first option of blank.
Is there a way to always redirect the user to the blank option rather than the selected key option?

***view.xml***

```
<Label text="Reason"/>
<ComboBox items="{path:'modelName'>/results'}">
    <items>
        <core:Item text="{modelName>description}" key="{modelName>code}"/>
    </items>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: You can provide a reset button next to the combobox which will clear the value and set the blank value.

Comment: Not sure about the scrolling to the first element using any standard way but 1. you can use ComboBox with filter option enabled so if user clears the selected value using backspace he should see the blank value first. 2.MultiComboBox always shows the top value first, no need to scroll to top, see if it fits your requirement. Thanks!